# SQL Server : When Not Matched Then Insert from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

Is it possible to select from the table being merged to while inserting into it? If so, how would I go about it.

Here is what I have but it is saying

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Code:

```
MERGE INTO TblPrem As MERC 
Using PremSvcXRef As ICE ON MERC.Premise = ICE.OldLocationNum 
                         AND MERC.PremiseServiceSeqNum IS NULL 
                         AND ICE.PremiseServiceSeqNum = (SELECT Min(PremiseServiceSeqNum)
                                                         FROM PremServXRef
                                                         WHERE MERC.Premise = OldLocationNum) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE 
      SET MERC.IcePremise = ICE.PremiseId,
          MERC.MercPremise = ICE.OldLocationNum,
          MERC.PremiseServiceSeqNum  = ICE.PremiseServiceSeqNum,
          MERC.MercCustNu = ICE.OldCustNum,
          MERC.IceCustNu = ICE.CustId

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT(Premise, Zone, Address, City, State, CustomerName, Status, 
          Notes, Exclude, LastUpdate, upsize_ts, FarmTap, MultiMeter, 
          Abandoned, CustID, PremiseServiceSeqNum, MercPremise, IcePremise, 
          MercCustNu, IceCustNu)
     SELECT TOP 1 
        *,
        ICE.PremiseServiceSeqNum,
        ICE.OldLocationNum,
        ICE.PremiseId,
        ICE.OldCustNum,
        ICE.CustId
     FROM 
        TblPremisesCopy A 
     WHERE 
        A.Premise = ICE.OldLocationNum;
```

Further explanation of what I'm trying to do:

There was a primary key of 'Premise' before but it is being changed to a key of 'Premise' and 'PremiseServiceSeqNum' and I am updating it with current values. When matched, it's updating the current record and when it's not I'm trying to duplicate the row of the table and update it with some other information.

Comment: You can't do an arbitrary `SELECT` in your `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause - all you can use are those columns that are defined as the `Source` in the `MERGE` statement (the `PremSvcXRef As ICE` table)

Comment: I am only using those columns that are defined as the Source, but I think it's probably not possible to do what I'm trying to do then. Is there any trick to insert when matched?